# GREP string to select 0 : wildcard words : hard return

Tags: adobe-indesign

How do you set up a find and replace GREP string to find in your document any line of copy (separated by 2 hard returns) that consist of a 'zero, space, wildcard word(s), hard return?

In the attached image it needs to find the:

0 civil

0 civil & criminal

but leave the:

4 criminal

1 cease & desist

2 pre action

Essentially, I'm trying to automate the deletion of any line of copy that has a zero value. (I have close on a hundred of these docs to edit) Any ideas?

Thanks
JK

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Find:

```
^0.+\v
```

Replace by nothing.

Comment: Could you break down the code a bit for me: what does it mean, what is it telling indesign to do? Thanks again.

Comment: Sure...^ means beginning of the paragraph, then 0 (zero) then any characters repeating (.+) and finally vertical space (\v). That includes soft and hard returns.

Comment: You're very welcome

Comment: Vinny, I hope you're online. Can you help me again? I have a text box with a hundred odd phrases listed, each on a new line separated by a hard return. I'd like to insert a " at the beginning and end of each phrase? Clever GREP solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: @JKCapeTown You should start a new question